# Android toast message from a separate thread class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, toast

I am confused about how to use Toast to print out messages.
I need to use it to print out messages that come from the thread's while loop.
My thread which renders graphics are on a different class than my activity.
I mean, they are not implemented in the same file.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```
myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

 public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
 }

});
```